# Return text between divs in jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

So I need to get the time between the divs.

```
<div class="episodeTime">12:00 am</div>
```

Using jsoup, the closest answer I could find to this was:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements times = doc.select("div[class=episodeTime]");
Element time = times.first();
```

However, `time` continues to return null. I have scoured the jsoup documentation along with questions here about it and cannot find a correct answer.  I'm not a jsoup guru so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe HTML code `Jsoup` is parsing is not the code you think it does. Remember that Jsoup has not JavaScript engine so it can't generate dynamic code like browsers do.

Comment: Try to print content of `doc` to see if there really is `<div class="episodeTime">12:00 am</div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me since I needed these objects in a `for` loop:

```
time.text();
```